# Text is changing in summernote while the user is typing

Tags: summernote

I have an exam using Summernote.

We have video of a user answering a question, and while she was typing, the text would change to what appears to be an answer from a previous question.

Using the Monty Python questions as an example,
Answer 1:  "Arthur, King of the Britons." (Saved and moved on. New page loaded with next question.)
Answer 2: user typing "To seek the Holy..." and all of a sudden, it flashes the previous answer, and the user continues typing "...Grail"

There is no autosave or autorefresh enabled.   Answers are loaded when navigate to, and saved on any page interactions outside the summernote div.  (i.e. Next or Previous clicked, or a question number on the index is clicked)

Has anyone ever seen this happen before?  Any ideas how to prevent it?